# Randomly pick two values greater than zero from a vector in python

Tags: python, vector

I have got a vector in python and I want to randomly pick two values from the vector X_valid (sized - 9 dimensions) with the condition that those two values are not zero. I can easily pick two values from my vector:

```
indx1 = randint(0, 8)
indx2 = randint(0, 8)
X_valid[0][indx1] = 0
X_valid[0][indx2] = 0
```

A sample of my vector is the following: `[13, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 0, 3, 0]`.
However I want to know, how can I pick those two values with the condition that `X_valid[0][indx1 or indx2]`  to be greater than zero. How can I perform that picking?

Comment: *Different* values/entries, or is picking the 13 twice or picking both 11s also ok?

Comment: Ideally differnet values (as it is right now it can pick the same two values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to get the indices of the non-zero elements and choose from them.

```
non_zero = [i for i, x in enumerate(X_valid) if x != 0]
X_valid[0][random.choice(non_zero)] = 0
```

However, this approach requires you to remove the first index from `non_zero` before choosing again, and could be relatively expensive if there are lots of non-zero elements to choose from.

An alternative approach is to just generate random indices until you find a non-zero element.

```
c = 2
while c > 0:
    index = randint(0,8)
    if X_valid[0][indx] == 0:
        continue
    X_valid[0][indx] = 0
    c = c - 1
```

Assuming there are lots of non-zero elements, it is unlikely that you will randomly choose multiple zero elements.

(Both approaches assume that there *are* sufficient non-zero elements to choose from; the first one makes it easier to detect when that is not the case.)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is typical:

```
while True:
    i = random.randint(0, 8)
    j = random.randint(0, 9)
    if i != j and X_valid[0][i] > 0 and X_valid[0][j] > 0:
        break
X_valid[0][i] = 0
X_valid[0][j] = 0
```

Of course, it will loop forever if the condition cannot be satisfied.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I'm positive that `[indx1 or indx2]` is not what is intended.